# A question about matrix jordan normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, jordan-normal-form

I tried to solve a problem:how to find the jordan normal from of the following matrix.

Assume $n\ge 2$ , let $A=(a_{ij})_{n\times n}.$
$$A=\left( \begin{matrix}
 0&  0&  0&  1&  1\\
 0&  0&  \unicode{x22f0}&  \unicode{x22f0}&  0\\
 0&  1&  1&  0&  0\\
 1&  1&  0&  0&  0\\
 1&  0&  0&  0&  0\\
\end{matrix} \right) \,\,,a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
 1,i+j\in \left\{ n,n+1 \right\}\\
 0,i+j\notin \left\{ n,n+1 \right\}\\
\end{cases}.$$

I  know $A$ is a symmetric matrix, so the jordan normal from of $A$ is a diagonal matrix. But computing the eigenvalues of $A$ may be difficult for me.

For example:

If n=3, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^3-\lambda^2-2\lambda+1.$

If n=4, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^4-\lambda^3-3\lambda^2+2\lambda+1.$

If n=5, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^5-\lambda^4-4\lambda^3+3\lambda^2+3\lambda-1.$

I can't find a general conclusions about eigenvalues or even solve the above polynomials.

So I would like to know if there is a general conclusion about the eigenvalues of the above matrix or how to give the jordan normal form of $A$.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be tough. Playing around a bit on a computer one sees that for some $n$ the characteristic polynomial $\chi_n$ is reducible, while for others it isn't. There also seems to be no clear pattern. Computing discriminants we get that for $2\leq n\leq 600$ they are all different from $0$ (trusting Maple on the computation). Thus we do know at least for these $n$ that $\chi_n$ has no duplicated roots and thus that the Jordan form is a diagonal matrix. Searching OEIS with the coefficients of $\chi_8$ we get among others [this](https://oeis.org/A108299). That's probably a start.

Comment: It took some more time, but I've tested with Maple $\text{discr}(\chi_n)\neq 0$ for $2\leq n\leq 1000$. So the Jordan form (over $\mathbb{C}$ or any other algebraically closed, characteristic $0$ field) is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Further "numerical" investigation shows for $2\leq n\leq 1000$: $\chi_n$ has (any number of) rational roots $\Leftrightarrow$ $\chi_n$ has a single rational root $\Leftrightarrow$ $\chi_n$ has the single rational root $1$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $n\equiv 1\bmod 3$.

Comment: Here is a list of all $2\leq n\leq 300$ for which the $\chi_n$ is reducible (over $\mathbb{Q}$) without a linear factor: ```[12, 17, 24, 27, 32, 38, 42, 45, 47, 57, 59, 60, 62, 66, 71, 72, 77, 80, 84, 87, 92, 93, 101, 102, 104, 107, 108, 110, 117, 122, 123, 126, 129, 132, 137, 143, 144, 147, 149, 150, 152, 159, 161, 162, 164, 167, 170, 171, 177, 180, 182, 185, 188, 192, 195, 197, 201, 203, 206, 207, 212, 213, 218, 222, 225, 227, 234, 236, 237, 240, 242, 246, 248, 252, 255, 257, 258, 263, 264, 266, 267, 269, 272, 275, 276, 279, 282, 287, 290, 291, 294, 297]```

Comment: @Thomas Preu Thanks! There may be no pattern to this question.  It is too difficult to solve the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Thomas Preu I appreciate your attempts.